# Relacionamento de Tabelas SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPITQ.png)**Tenho três tabelas Produto, Grupo e Subgrupo**,
01 - para um produto existir é preciso existir um grupo.
02 - para um sub grupo existir é preciso ter um grupo.

Na tabela de Produtos eu não precisaria ter o campo subgrupo uma vez que o mesmo já é chave primaria entre subgrupo e grupo

porem quando consulto o produto, ele trás o grupo, e um grupo tem vários subgrupos, relacionei desta forma conforme a imagem, alguém pode informar se esse relacionamento é correto ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Eu relacionaria desse formato,

Grupo seria a PK, Subgrupo usando a FK do Grupo e Produto ia usar as duas FK Grupo e Subgrupo

TABLE GRUPO
id_grupo INT  PRIMARY KEY

TABLE SUBGRUPO
id_subgrupo INT PRIMARY KEY
FOREIGN KEY (id_grupo) REFERENCES Grupo(id_grupo)

TABLE PRODUTO
id_produto INT PRIMARY KEY
FOREIGN KEY (id_grupo) REFERENCES Grupo(id_grupo)
FOREIGN KEY (id_subgrupo) REFERENCES Subgrupo(id_subgrupo)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).